# How do I encrypt an Azure Function's Connection String to ServiceBus

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I've started a new Azure Function project that is intended to listen to an Azure Service Bus. Placing the connection string in the `local.settings.json` file works fine when the `Connection` property of the service bus trigger is set.

The problem comes in that I need the service bus connection string to be encrypted in the application settings.

How can I setup service bus to decrypt the string before using it to connect to service bus?

There doesn't appear to be any service bus setup options available off of `IFunctionHostBuilder` either. So what can I hook into to have an encrypted connection string be decrypted?

Comment: "how'd you think this is secure", nobody is debating the security of encrypting the connection string in a config file. This is simply a requirement I'm trying to handle. If there is no solution because this is simply something that should not be done, that's great but for now the question is simply how to accomplish the task without debating whether the string should or should not be encrypted.

Comment: Well I'm asking how, given an encrypted connection string, how do I pass the decrypted string to the service bus trigger?

Comment: You possibly could inherit the `ServiceBusTrigger Attribute`, pass the decrypted string to it?

Comment: That's a possibility, the other option I have would be to intercept the configurationRoot and rewrite it during startup. If there's no better way I may end up doing one of these options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection string is going to need to be read by a few pieces of the infrastructure to work as expected.  Some of it is the runtime (which in theory you could hack together, but I wouldn’t recommend it), but also pieces that monitor event rates and scale to do things like activate the function when a queue message arrives (which is managed code in Azure you couldn’t hack to decrypt).

I think from a security aspect I’d recommend the approach of [putting your connection strings in Key Vault Secrets](https://medium.com/statuscode/getting-key-vault-secrets-in-azure-functions-37620fd20a0b) which are themselves encrypted, and then using the linked integration so that Azure Functions runtime and hosted components can securely retrieve the connection string as needed

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yeah the Key Vault is likely the best way to go but right now not an option for me. I ended up just decrypting the connection string and replacing it in the registered services during startup. That seems to be the earliest interception point so all downstream consumers get a clear string.